# Use list comprehension to replace nested for loop

Tags: python

This nested for loop accomplishes my goal but I would like to do it using list comprehension and/or lambda func

```
new_a=[]
new_b=[]
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]

for num_a in a:
    for num_b in b:
        new_a.append(num_a)
        new_b.append(num_b)

print(new_a)
print(new_b)
```

output:

```
new_a=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

new_b=[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

I can get *new_a* with `[num for num in a for num in b]`

but can't figure out how to get *new_b* using listcomp or lambda

Comment: Maybe: `new_b = b * len(a)`

Comment: `[num_b for num_a in a for num_b in b]`?

Comment: Agree with @MarkMeyer; sometimes you don’t need comprehension/loop/etc.  Similar for `new_a`, if you wanted to use `numpy`: `np.repeat([1,2,3], 3)`.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `itertools.permutations`

Comment: @S3DEV I'd be hesitant to include something as heavy weight as numpy for this unless it was already in the project, but generally agree.

Comment: @flakes - Yes, absolutely agreed.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is just use the length of the one array to perform the operation on the other. You could use `for _ in range(len(old))`, but just iterating over the list and ignoring the output performs the same thing. The trick here is the arrangement of for loops

```
old_a = [1, 2, 3]
old_b = [1, 2, 3]

new_a = [a for a in old_a for _ in old_b]
new_b = [b for _ in old_a for b in old_b]

print(new_a)
print(new_b)
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) along with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) function to do that:

```
new_a, new_b = map(list,zip(*[[num_a, num_b] for num_a in a for num_b in b]))

print(new_a)
print(new_b)
```

This will return:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]

new_a=list(el for el1 in zip(* [a]*len(b)) for el in el1)
new_b=b*len(a)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> new_a
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] 

>>> new_b
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```